# Figuring out the variables rows and colums for matrices

Tags: matrices, solution-verification

Let $P$ be a $2 \times 3$ matrix, $Q$ an $m \times 5$ matrix, and $R$ a $p \times q$ matrix. Find the values of $m$, $p$, and $q$ such that the operation $Q - PR$ is possible.

So I figured that $p = 3$.

Is $m=2$ and $q=5$?

Just need to make sure I'm on the right track.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply matrices, the inner dimensions have to match, and the result has the outer dimensions.

Here, we are multiplying $P$, which is $\color{red}{2} \times \color{blue}{3}$, with $R$, which is $\color{blue}{p} \times \color{red}{q}$.

In order to multiply the two matrices, we must have $\color{blue}{3} = \color{blue}{p}$, and the result $PR$ will have dimenions $\color{red}{2} \times \color{red}{q}$.  Since we are adding the matrix $PR$ with $Q$, which is $m \times 5$, their dimensions must match, which means we must have $m = 2$ and $q = 5$.

So yes, you were on the right track.